# What is the constructor for Firebase Storage Reference?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

So I tried to follow the tutorial on youtube about Firebase Storage, and I found this code:

```
val filePathAndName="product_images/"+""+timeStamp
val storageReference=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(filePathAndName)
```

But the code above uses Java in the tutorial, I changed it to Kotlin syntax and I tried to run the application and it worked.

After reading the documentation regarding Firebase Storage, I found:

```
// Create a child reference
// imagesRef now points to "images"
var imagesRef: StorageReference? = storageRef.child("images")

// Child references can also take paths
// spaceRef now points to "images/space.jpg
// imagesRef still points to "images"
var spaceRef = storageRef.child("images/space.jpg")
```

So what is the proper way to declare a reference? And what is the function of `filePathAndName` on `getReference(filePathAndName)`? Does it have the same functionality as a child in Kotlin syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an instance of [`FirebaseStorage`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/storage/FirebaseStorage) you can call [`reference`/`getReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/storage/FirebaseStorage#getreference) on it to get a [`StorageReference` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference) to the root, or (by passing in a path string) to a specific file.

When you have a `StorageReference` object, you can call `child(...)` on it to get a reference to a location under that reference.

It's similar to how you deal with directories in many other parts of programming: you can either pass in the entire path to a file right away, or you can pass in parts of the path and build the same path that way.

---

So as shown in the documentation on [creating references](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/create-reference), you can get a reference to the root with:

```
var storageRef = storage.reference
```

From there, you can then get a reference to a specific file with:

```
var spaceRef = storageRef.child("images/space.jpg")
```

But you can also replace the above two lines with this single line:

```
var storageRef = storage.getReference("images/space.jpg")
```

The above approaches have the exact same result, and it makes no practical difference which one you use (as these references are lightweight objects that make no call to the network yet).